# Python - Function to return a tuple with min, max, sum and average for all positive numbers in l

Tags: python

First post and beginner with python here.  I have the following question I'm trying to answer.  I pieced something together but getting constant errors back trying to figure out for the all positive numbers portion. Second portion is to identify any non-floating numbers.

Write a function get_all_stats that takes a list l of float pointing numbers as an argument and returns a tuple of the min, max, sum, and average of all *positive* numbers in l.

In addition, it returns "Invalid value!" if l has any non-floating point number

```
get_all_stats([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3, -1.0])

def get_all_stats(l):
    l_tmp = [num for num in l]
    return(min(l_tmp),max(l_tmp),sum(l_tmp),sum(l_tmp)/len(l_tmp))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!    Would you mind editing your post and showing us the full traceback of the error you're receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
from itertools import repeat

def get_all_stats(data):
    lst = [item for item in data if item >=0]
    if not all(map(isinstance, lst, repeat(float))):
        return None
    return (min(lst), max(lst), sum(lst), sum(lst)/len(lst))

data = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, -1]
result = get_all_stats(data)
if result:
    print(result)
else:
    print("Invalid value!")
```

```
(1.0, 3.0, 9.0, 2.25)
```

Comment: result is (-1.0, 3.0, 8.0, 1.6)

Comment: Thanks Jason...added some info below.  I think maybe you missed those 2 added pieces on top of what i supplied.

Comment: get_all_stats([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3, -1.0]) Based on the list about with the negative, it should be ignored and give me this output: (1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 2.0). 2.0 ? not 2.25 ?

Answer (score 0):

get_all_stats([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3, -1.0])

Based on the list about with the negative, it should be ignored and give me this output: (1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 2.0).

And if the values are ([1.0, 2.0, 3, -1.0])  I should get output: 'Invalid value!'.

Those 2 extra steps on top of what i already provided are what I'm having trouble with.